# Chain multiple promise.all() statements

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and am having a hard time chaining multiple promise.all() statements. Below is a highly simplified version of my code.

```js
function a(x) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve(x*2), 500)
   });
}

function b(x) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve(x*3), 400)
   });
}

function c(x) {
    const promises = [a(x),b(x)];
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(y){
        z = y[0] + y[1]
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(z);
        });
    }); 
}

function d(x) {
    const promises = [];
    for (let input of x){
        promises.push(c(input))
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(z){
        console.log(z);
    });
}

const data = [1,2,3,4,5];
d(data);
```

I'd like to see this printed:

```
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

But instead I'm seeing this:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You c function isn't returning anything

Comment: @PatrickEvans What do you mean? Isn't it returning a promise?

Comment: Hey User. Well asked question - just note that you can embed javascript/html/css straight into your quesiton - which makes it much easier to answer!

Comment: it is returning something in the callback but that doesn't do a return in the parent c function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `c` function isn't returning anything at the moment, resulting in `undefined`. Instead, `return` the `Promise.all` call, and after the `Promise.all` resolves, return `y[0] + y[1]` in the `.then` so that the consumer of `c` (in `d`) has access to the resolved value.

Also, avoid the [explicit Promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) - if you already have a `Promise` to work with, there should be no need to call `new Promise` to construct a separate one. Instead, just call `.then` on the existing `Promise`.

```
function c(x) {
    const promises = [a(x),b(x)];
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(y){
        return y[0] + y[1]
    }); 
}
```

```js
function a(x) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve(x*2), 500)
   });
}

function b(x) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve(x*3), 400)
   });
}

function c(x) {
    const promises = [a(x),b(x)];
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(y){
        return y[0] + y[1]
    }); 
}

function d(x) {
    const promises = [];
    for (let input of x){
        promises.push(c(input))
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(z){
        console.log(z);
    });
}

const data = [1,2,3,4,5];
d(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code was that you were not returning the promises from your functions `c(x)` and `d(x)`.

```
function a(x) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve(x * 2), 500)
    })
}

function b(x) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve(x * 3), 400)
    })
}

function c(x) {
    const promises = [a(x), b(x)]
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(y) {
        z = y[0] + y[1]
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve(z)
        })
    })
}

function d(x) {
    const promises = []
    for (let input of x) {
        promises.push(c(input))
    }
    return Promise.all(promises)
}

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
d(data) // then [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ]
```